# Canonical url being linked on Facebook rather than real URL. Dynamic OpenGraph tags coming up wrong

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook, seo, facebook-opengraph

I have a link curation website, so the problem is when I share a resource at the moment, the url could be for example http://mixtalker.com/?resources=looping-traktor-track-decks but facebook will scrape http://mixtalker.com/ because that is the canonical url.

This really sucks when someone posts it on facebook because all the OpenGraph tags are with the homepage meta, so the link gets the wrong thumbnail and wrong information. Who knows how to fix this?

Ps: Everything its ok with other pages, like about, faq, etc. I have this bug only with the link content page. Im Using Yoast SEO and Wordpress

Answer (score 0):

This is in the source:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://mixtalker.com/" />
```

You need to change that metatag to include the parameter:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://mixtalker.com/?resources=looping-traktor-track-decks" />
```